# mysql работает неправильно

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

В `php` отправляется `html` страница в виде текста, её нужно сохранить в mysql.

Страница получается большая, размер страницы заранее не знаем.

Пытаюсь сохранить её так:

```
$webpage = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['webpage']));
$query = "INSERT INTO webpages VALUES (NULL, '$webpage', '$date')";
$save = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
```

Что происходит после записи? А ничего не происходит, ничего не записывается.

Если отправить страницу меньше, где-то на 500 тыс. символов, страница сохранится без проблем.

Для меня самое важное сохранить полученную страницу, поэтому пришло только такое решение :

```
if(strlen($webpage) > 500000){
    $wbp1 = substr($webpage, 0, 500000);
    $wbp2 = substr($webpage, 500000, strlen($webpage));

    $query = "INSERT INTO webpages VALUES (NULL, '$wbp1', '$date')";
    $save = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
    $query = "INSERT INTO webpages VALUES (NULL, '$wbp2', '$date')";
    $save = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
}
else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO webpages VALUES (NULL, '$webpage', '$date')";
    $save = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error!" . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Что происходит теперь? Что-то мне не понятное.

Как я уже говорил, размер страницы я заранее знать не могу.

Некоторые страницы сохраняются в 2 записи `mysql`, а вот некоторые сохраняются в 1 и с обрезанным текстом.

В чём проблема? Я уже несколько дней не могу понять почему оно текст обрезает. Уменьшение до `400000` или `300000` релузьтат не меняют.

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема в размере, а не в каком-нибудь сложном символе посреди текста, который всё обрезает?

Comment: Но я же использую `htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['webpage']));`

Comment: Это экранирует строго ограниченный набор символов, и проблемные юникодные символы могут остаться неэкранированными.

Comment: Когда пытаются в одном огромном PHP-файле написать всю возможную обработку, мало того, что получается спагетти-код, так ещё и не поймёшь с чем проблема: толи файл не сохраняется из-за большого размера, толи символ некорректный посередине (валидация отстутствует), толи что-то ещё. Вам настоятельно рекомендовано разделить на отдельные операции (см. ответ Andrew например) и когда вы будете точно знать в каком месте ошибка -- тогда и задавать вопрос. А сейчас у вас "угадай мелодию": непонятно в каком месте вообще ошибка.

Comment: Приведённый код -- это только один фрагмент вашего огромного файла (который весь приводить нет никакого резона: обязанность автора сделать МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ пример), ошибка же может быть за границами приведённого фрагмента.

Comment: Наверное, это проклятие на века, переучивать всех использовать подготовленные запросы. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Не плохое решение для такого, сохранять страницу как файл, а в БД сохранять только адрес на этот файл.